# Stripe PaymentIntent Search or List expand parameter?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am building out a custom report generator for my bookkeeper and want to make sure I am going about this the right way.  We are passing in the metadata with stripe elements into the paymentintent.  They are showing up in the dashboard and I am able to use the paymentintent search endpoint successfully:

`payment_intents/search?query=status:'succeeded' AND metadata['main_event_code']:'1006'`

But now I need to gather the expanded info for this PI to get the rest of the data (stripe fees, application fees, etc).  I know in `stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve` I can pass `expand[0]=charges.data.balance_transaction` to see fee, net, etc.

But I am trying to see the same data when using `stripe.PaymentIntent.search` or  `stripe.PaymentIntent.list`
But When I do I get:

`This property cannot be expanded (charges). You may want to try expanding 'data.charges' instead.`

So if I need to use search or list then do I need to just foreach each returned PI? Or is there a way to expand on lists or search?

Comment: you will have better luck on the stripe developers channel on Discord.  There are stripe developers there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) functionality on both the List All [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list) API and the [Search PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/search) API. Instead of passing passing `expand: ['charges']`, since the `charges` is nested under `data` array, you'd need to pass `expand: ['data.charges']`. I tested this on my test account and it works.

Comment: yeah I learned from the discord channel because it's an array I need to add data to the front.  When set it to ```data.charges.data.balance_transaction``` it worked.